# Internal Frame Listener not working

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jinternalframe

The following code below shows an internal frame listener for the Gui class. The internal frame listener should either set the save (JMenuItem) as enable or disabled but it does nothing. I don't know where the problem is. I have tried a couple of things but nothing works.

Here is the code:

```
public class Gui implements InternalFrameListener, ActionListener{

MyInternalFrame frame;
JMenuItem save;

public Gui( JDesktopPane desktop, final JMenuItem save) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    frame = new MyInternalFrame(title, img);
     this.save = save;
    frame.setVisible(true); 
    desktop.add(frame);
    try {
            frame.setSelected(true);
    } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {

    }
   frame.addInternalFrameListener(this);  

       // options(name, desktop);

}

class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {

    static final int xPosition = 30, yPosition = 30;
    public MyInternalFrame(String title, ImagePlus img) {
        super(title, true,true, true, true);
        setSize(img.getHeight(), img.getWidth());

        // Set the window's location.
        setLocation(xPosition * openFrameCount, yPosition * openFrameCount);
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    frame.addInternalFrameListener(this);
    System.out.println("beingg called");
}



@Override
public void internalFrameActivated(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    save.setEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    save.setEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    save.setEnabled(false);

}

@Override
public void internalFrameDeactivated(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    save.setEnabled(false);

}

@Override
public void internalFrameDeiconified(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    save.setEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    save.setEnabled(false);

}

@Override
public void internalFrameOpened(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    save.setEnabled(true);

}

 }
```

Comment: This should throw a NullPointerException, because save is never assigned.

Comment: Where is your MyInternalFrame class I do not see any where in the code?????

Comment: If possible please post the source code of MyInternalFrame class. Additionally super(imp) gives a compile time error, you haven't defined what imp is?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to copy things. I think everything is in there now. I don't get any null pointer exception error. I just can't get my internal frame listener to work. Can anybody see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing that this is working in general. My guess would be that you are using a wrong instance of the `save` menu item. In doubt, add debug output

```
    @Override
    public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent arg0)
    {
        System.out.println("Disabling "+save);
        save.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

to your methods.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent;
import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameListener;

public class InternalFrameListenerTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
        menubar.add(menu);
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
        menu.add(menuItem);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);
        JDesktopPane d = new JDesktopPane();
        Gui gui = new Gui(d, menuItem);

        frame.getContentPane().add(d);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Gui implements InternalFrameListener, ActionListener
{

    MyInternalFrame frame;
    JMenuItem save;

    public Gui(JDesktopPane desktop, final JMenuItem save)
    {
        frame = new MyInternalFrame("Title");
        this.save = save;
        frame.setVisible(true);
        desktop.add(frame);
        try
        {
            frame.setSelected(true);
        }
        catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e)
        {

        }
        frame.addInternalFrameListener(this);
    }

    class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame
    {

        static final int xPosition = 30, yPosition = 30;

        public MyInternalFrame(String title)
        {
            super(title, true, true, true, true);
            setSize(200,100);
            setLocation(50,50);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        frame.addInternalFrameListener(this);
        System.out.println("beingg called");
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameActivated(InternalFrameEvent arg0)
    {
        save.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent arg0)
    {
        save.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent arg0)
    {
        save.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameDeactivated(InternalFrameEvent arg0)
    {
        save.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameDeiconified(InternalFrameEvent arg0)
    {
        save.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent arg0)
    {
        save.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameOpened(InternalFrameEvent arg0)
    {
        save.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```